# How do I merge 2 branches in GIT into one branch with 2 folders

Tags: git, merge

I have an application in a git repo, but it is meant to eventually be a class of applications. So my plan is to make a folder structure like

```
lib/ - common to all
app1/
  lib/ - link to above folder
app2/ 
  lib/ - link to above folder
...
```

Currently it is

```
lib/ 
other code right here
```

And we have a seperate branch which is morphing into the 2nd of this class of apps. So I want to restructure the Repo as I indicate above, without losing the commits if possible. 
I did the restructure on master, but I am not sure how to merge now. I tried to restructure the branch into `app2/` but all that does is create conflict.. Is there a git way to do what I am trying?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If submodules aren't the answer, and you really want to merge a number of git repos, the answer is actually quite easy.

```
git filter-branch --tree-filter 'if [ -f old ]; then mkdir dir && mv old dir/new; fi' HEAD
```

With a bit of tree filter logic, on each of APP1 and APP2 repos, you can mould them into looking exactly like they need to look when you later merge them.

You can then, from the main repo,

```
git remote add remote1 <url to app 1 repo>
git fetch --all
git merge remote1/<branch>

git remote add remote2 <url to app 2 repo>
git fetch --all
git merge remote2/<branch>
```

Once you have done this, and confirmed your repository looks good, its simply a matter of pushing your current branch.

Comment: Its not 2 repos, but 2 branches on the same repo.. not sure if that affects your answer

Comment: Its should still work.  Use filter branch to rename the files in one branch, then merge to pull the renamed files into the other branch..

Comment: Hey I am trying to do this.. I know `dir` should be the dirname i want, but what about old and new?

Comment: In the example, "old" and "new" are the original and final file names.  I often use "mkdir newfolder; mv * newfolder || true'.  The '||true' ensures the filter branch continues if the mv returns errors.  possibly dangerous, but it works for me.

Comment: So I do this once for every file involved?

Comment: In a way.  `git filter-branch` automates this for you for every commit in the git repository.

Comment: Got it working with scripting it through https://gist.github.com/ktaragorn/1b5468843e587e818383. Basically doubled my git history but should be simpler to work now for the future. In the gist, `clowns_as_many` is the new folder

Comment: Also I needed to fix a issue with `mkdir` which failed on the 2nd run, since the folder already existed then. did it by using `-p` instead which doesnt fail if the folder exists. Didnt have any issues with `mv`

Comment: I learned recently that "git read-tree" might also fit the bill... It combines the filterbranch style rename, and the merge, but be careful, if you don't follow the right instructions, you will not get a merge parent, and further merges become impossible.   ( https://help.github.com/articles/about-git-subtree-merges/ )

Answer (score 2):

It would be better if you could:

- [split your repo](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Split+a+repository+in+two#Splitarepositoryintwo-UsingGittosplit-outadirectory) into `lib`, `app1`, `app2`
- add in `app1` repo a **[submodule](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules)** reference to the `lib` repo
- add in `app2` repo a **[submodule](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules)** reference to the `lib` repo

That way, each app repos do reference an exact version of the lib repo.

Comment: This was my first thought, but these are meant to be simple apps, and was hoping for a simple method. Also submodules are a pain on their own.

Comment: +1 This is the way to do it. Repositories are dead simple; there is nothing wrong in creating separate ones for each separate app. On the other hand, mixing the development of two separate apps and a shared library not only in the same repository but also in the same history line (=branch) seems really wrong.